# Counting combined occurrences across two columns

Tags: r, find-occurrences

Hi I have a data frame Y which looks like the following

```
O  T  Dist
2  13 0.123 
2  3  0.452
2  4  0.213
3  5  0.231
3  8  0.213
4  5  0.123
5  8  0.543
```

I wish to create a new data frame which counts the total number of times a number appears in the O column and the T column combines. The output should look like.

```
P  freq 
2  3
3  3
4  2
5  3
8  2
13 1
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
as.data.frame(table(c(df$O, df$T)))
  Var1 Freq
1    2    3
2    3    3
3    4    2
4    5    3
5    8    2
6   13    1
```

Comment: It would not. I would only consider the first column, and he wants the first two columns combined

Answer (score 1):

```
counts = table(c(df$O,df$T))
new.df = data.frame(P=as.integer(names(counts)),Freq=as.integer(counts))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`, where we select the columns "O", "T" in dataset  "Y" (`Y[-3]`), `unlist`, create a "data.table" with `setDT(list(..))`, group by 'V1' and get the counts (`.N`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(list(unlist(Y[-3])))[,.N, keyby=V1]
#   V1 N
#1:  2 3
#2:  3 3
#3:  4 2
#4:  5 3
#5:  8 2
#6: 13 1
```